# The docker.sock file does not exist when docker volume was set

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to get docker daemon information of host from docker container.

So I started the docker as follows, but I couldn't find the docker.sock file.

```
docker run -d --restart=always --privileged \
        --name="MY_CONTAINER" \
        -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup \
        -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
        -d myimg:base.01
```

In Host

```
$ ls -al /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0  3월 16 09:05 /var/run/docker.sock
```

In Container

```
$ ls -al /var/run/docker.sock
ls: cannot access /var/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7.6.1810
COPY ./myfiles/var /var
RUN \
        (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
        rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
        rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
        rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
        rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
        rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
        rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
        rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
\
ENTRYPOINT [ "/sbin/init" ]
```

Docker inspect

```
$ docker inspect MY_CONTAINER

"Mounts": [
    {       
        "Type": "bind", 
        "Source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "Destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },      
    {       
        "Type": "bind", 
        "Source": "/lib/modules",
        "Destination": "/lib/modules",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },      
    {       
        "Type": "bind", 
        "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
        "Destination": "/var/run/docker.sock",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }       
],
```

Why is this?

And how to fix?

Comment: Is systemd clearing out `/var/run` as part of its normal "initialize the entire host" sequence?  Or unmounting all of the bind-mount content?  Do you have the same problem if you avoid systemd, and `docker run ... centos ls -l /var/run/docker.sock` with otherwise similar mount options?

Comment: @DavidMaze I changed ENTRYPOINT to CMD in dockerfile and tried to `run ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`. And then the file exist ! The file does not exist if i didn't set ls command for the same image to perform the following command: `docker exec -it MY_CONTAINER /bin/bash`

Comment: @DavidMaze what's mean "initialize the entier host" ?

Comment: If you look at [the systemd home page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) it sets up a _ton_ of things (swap, file system mounts, dbus, ...) most of which are unnecessary or impossible in a container environment.  If that includes wiping out `/var/run` or mounting a new tmpfs there, that could cause this problem.  It's usually better practice to not run systemd in a container, but instead directly run the single process you need to run as the container `CMD`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand. Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

same problem with me.

I found that if don't set `ENTRYPOINT` to `init`, `/var/run/docker.sock` would be exist. but if I set `ENTRYPOINT` to `init`, it would be not exist.

And my solve way is that, volume `/var/run/docker.sock` to other dir (just not `/var/run/` and `/run/`) and set a systemd service(may there is other way in centos) to softlink it to `/var/run/docker.sock` when container start.

example:

1. `docker-entrypoint.sh`

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   ln -sf /etc/fix-docker-sock/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
   ```
2. `fix-docker-sock.service`

   ```bash
   [Unit]
   Description=docker.sock fix
   After=syslog.target network.target

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/etc/fix-docker-sock/docker-entrypoint.sh
   Type=oneshot

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. `Dockerfile`

   ```
   FROM debian:11.7
   LABEL authors="Wankko Ree"

   RUN apt-get update && \
       apt-get -y install systemd systemd-sysv curl wget vim git net-tools iputils-ping && \
       apt-get clean && \
       rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

   RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sh get-docker.sh && systemctl enable docker

   COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /etc/fix-docker-sock/
   COPY fix-docker-sock.service /etc/systemd/system/

   RUN chmod +x /etc/fix-docker-sock/docker-entrypoint.sh && \
       chmod -x /etc/systemd/system/fix-docker-sock.service && systemctl enable fix-docker-sock

   ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]
   ```
4. `docker-compose.yml`

   ```yaml
   version: "3"

   services:
     fix-docker-sock:
       container_name: fix-docker-sock
       build: .
       stdin_open: true
       tty: true
       privileged: true
       volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/etc/fix-docker-sock/docker.sock
   ```